# Call Uniswap V3 QuoterV2 `quoteExactOutput()` function with dart (flutter)

Tags: dart, ethereum, decentralized-applications, uniswap, web3dart

I am trying to call [`quoteExactOutput()`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e#writeContract) from [Uniswap V3 QuoterV2](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/lens/Quoter#quoteexactoutput) with dart.

This `quoteExactOutput()` function is not a `view` function. Therefore, what I want is to **call the function without sending a transaction** to the Ethereum blockchain (only to simulate the call).

What I expect from calling that function is to get the equivalent WETH amount of UNI token, e.g., `1.0 WETH is equal to 286.48961882910004 UNI`.

Here is what I tried to call `quoteExactOutput`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:token_price_uniswap/utils/constant.dart';
import 'package:web3dart/web3dart.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<DeployedContract> loadContract() async {
  final contract = DeployedContract(
      ContractAbi.fromJson(uniswapV3QuoterV2Abi, "UniswapV3Quoter2"),
      EthereumAddress.fromHex(uniswapV3QuoterV2Address));
  return contract;
}

Future<String> sendTx(
  String funcname,
  List<dynamic> args,
  Web3Client ethClient,
  String privateKey,
) async {
  EthPrivateKey credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(privateKey);
  DeployedContract contract = await loadContract();
  final ethFunction = contract.function(funcname);
  final result = await ethClient.sendTransaction(
      credentials,
      Transaction.callContract(
        contract: contract,
        function: ethFunction,
        parameters: args,
      ),
      chainId: null,
      fetchChainIdFromNetworkId: true);
  return result;
}

Future<List<dynamic>> fetchFromContract(
    String funcName, List<dynamic> args, Web3Client ethClient) async {
  final contract = await loadContract();
  final calledFunction = contract.function(funcName);
  final result = ethClient.call(
    contract: contract,
    function: calledFunction,
    params: args,
  );

  return result;
}

Future<List> getWeth(Web3Client ethClient) async {
  List<dynamic> result = await fetchFromContract("WETH9", [], ethClient);

  print("called Uniswap V3 WETH");
  return result;
}

Future<List<dynamic>> quoteExactOutput(
  Web3Client ethClient,
  List<int> path,
  String amountIn,
) async {
  final amountInBigInt = BigInt.parse(amountIn);

  final params = [
    path,
    amountInBigInt, // Convert BigInt to int
  ];
  print("params: $path");

  final result = await fetchFromContract('quoteExactOutput', params, ethClient);

  return result;
}

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  Web3Client? ethClient;
  Client? httpClient;

  httpClient = Client();
  ethClient = Web3Client(rpcUrl, httpClient);

  String wethAmount = '1000000000000000000'; // 1 WETH
  final path = [uniswapTokenAddress, 3000, wethTokenAddress];

  // call quote exact input
  final encodedPath = encode(path);
  var result = await quoteExactOutput(ethClient, encodedPath, wethAmount);
  print("1 WETH is equal to ${result[0]} UNI");
}
```

However, I got this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
RPCError: got code -32000 with msg "execution reverted".
#0      JsonRPC.call (package:web3dart/json_rpc.dart:71:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Web3Client.makeRPCCall (package:web3dart/src/core/client.dart:53:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Web3Client.call (package:web3dart/src/core/client.dart:408:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      quoteExactOutput(package:token_price_uniswap/services/uniswap_v3_functions.dart:108:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (file:///D:/Eight/Programs/token_price_uniswap/bin/token_price_uniswap.dart:40:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I suspect I made the `path` parameter incorrectly. What I know is in Solidity, we can create the `path` argument by using `abi.encodePacked()`. However, I do not know how to create the `path` with similar `abi.encodePacked()` function version in dart.

However, I tried with Python and it was success. Here is the code with Python (tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/@crjameson/calculating-the-optimal-token-amounts-before-swapping-on-uniswap-v2-and-uniswap-v3-in-python-acf5f5c6d47e))

```
from web3 import Web3
import eth_abi.packed
import json

# setup our account and chain connection - we will use infura here
rpc_endpoint = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/INFURA_ID" # 
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_endpoint))

# some addresses first
UNISWAP_v3_QUOTER2_ADDRESS = "0x61fFE014bA17989E743c5F6cB21bF9697530B21e"
UNISWAP_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984"
WETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"

# Load abi
f = open('./assets/uniswap_v3_quoter2.json')
UNISWAP_V3_QUOTER2_ABI = json.load(f)

# load the contracts
quoter2_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=UNISWAP_v3_QUOTER2_ADDRESS, abi=UNISWAP_V3_QUOTER2_ABI)

# prepare the function call parameters
path = eth_abi.packed.encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [WETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS, 3000, UNISWAP_TOKEN_ADDRESS])
amount_to_buy_for = 1 * 10**18

# call quote exact output
amount_out, sqrtPriceX96After, initializedTicksCrossed, gasEstimate = quoter2_contract.functions.quoteExactOutput(path, amount_to_buy_for).call()
print(f"for {amount_to_buy_for/10**18} WETH you would get {amount_out/10**18} UNI token")
```

output:

```
for 1.0 UNI token you have to pay 284.3230485269558 WETH
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was in the encode function in the dart. This is the code that equivalent to `abi.encodePacked(address token0, uint24 fee, address token1)` to generate the path needed from `quoteExactOutput()` function with dart:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

Uint8List createPath(
    String token0, String amount, String token1) {
  // Encode parameters
  String amountHex =
      BigInt.from(int.parse(amount)).toUnsigned(24).toRadixString(16);
  String pathHex = token0.replaceAll('0x', '') +
      amountHex.padLeft(6, '0') + // Pad the amount to 6 bytes since the fee is in uint24
      token1.replaceAll('0x', '');

  // Convert the hexadecimal string to bytes
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(hex.decode(pathHex));

  return bytes;
}
```

to see whether the output the same with solidity, we can check it by using the following function:

```
String bytesToString(Uint8List bytes) {
  // Convert bytes to hexadecimal string
  String hexString = hex.encode(bytes);
  return hexString;
}
```